# Where is implementation detail of printToConsole of Flutter

Tags: flutter

When `print('test')` is executed with Flutter, logs are output like

```
flutter I: test
```

on Android. I wanted to control the log and looked at the print implementation, and `printToConsole` is used inside print.
However, no implementation of `printToConsole` was found.
Does anyone know where the implementation of `printToConsole` is on each platform?

Comment: see `runZoned` global function from `dart:async` library

Comment: @pskink Is there any URL of github?